# In test.py, how do I create a user, add user to group in the setUp function?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Writing tests, most of my app is hidden unless you belong to a certain group, so I will need to make a test user that belongs to that group. I want to do this in the setUp function so all following functions can use this user.

Answer (score 0):

Just add it:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.user = User.objects.create(...)
    self.special_group = Group.objects.create(...)
    self.user.groups.add(special_group)
```

Comment: no login required? and do I need to create the group in the test as well?

Comment: Yes, create a group, add the user to such group and test. You can use the  `auth.login` method in order to login your test user or  `test.Client.login`  if you're using `test.Client` to test views. But hey, that's another question ;)

Comment: Where can i find the documentation on this, my google fu has failed me into finding these things. Because I wouldn't know how to create a new group or login a user in test.py

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you right. Creating a group is something I write in the test.py? How? Can you link me to the docs where all this is explained. There seems to be very little info online about testing in Django compared to all the other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

First create a test user in your local DB and then simply create a fixture file using **manage.py dumpdata** command. This will create fixtures file as given below:

```
[{"model": "auth.user",
"pk": 1,
"fields": {
  "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$24000$myfvqrG84hps$vkEWoQW3L7MsnBI90H/5TBzV8Ad1cQVm1zFms6e4eEE=",
  "last_login": "2017-03-20T07:02:48.575Z",
  "is_superuser": true,
  "username": "test",
  "first_name": "",
  "last_name": "",
  "email": "",
  "is_staff": true, "is_active": true,
  "date_joined": "2016-01-07T11:22:24.007Z",
  "groups": [],
  "user_permissions": []}}]
```

Suppose the name of the file is "xyz.json" then load this fixture file as given below:

```
class ResourcesTestCase(TestCase):
fixtures = ['xyz']
```

You are done and now you can use "test" user in your testcases wherever you want.

Comment: In my test,py how can I log this user in and check if he's logged in?

Comment: Also, groups and user_permissions don't seem to be part of the auth.user model, as they are in seperate tables in the database.

Comment: My database is slight different from yours so once you use manage.py dumpdata <appname> then it will create fixtures JSON as per your current schema.

Comment: @user1880554 You can use `self.client.login(username='test', password='yourpassword')` to login with this test user. Sample code: `cookie = self.client.cookies['sessionid']
        self.selenium.get(self.live_server_url + '/admin/')
        self.selenium.add_cookie({'name': 'sessionid', 'value': cookie.value, 'secure': False, 'path': '/'})
        self.selenium.refresh()`

Comment: but how do I show in my test if the user is logged in and what it's groups are? I've gotten multiple solutions on how to create a user with group, but I can't actually check them in the test, and being logged in / belonging to a group should have given me different http responses.

Comment: As I mentioned above, you can login through this and as you mentioned that this user must be having some rights so just hit that URL and check whether it allows this user to access it or not. This would solve your problem.

Comment: This is not my problem, I know what's supposed to log me in, but I can not let the test see me who is logged in, as it doesn't seem to care if a user exists or not when trying to log in.

Comment: test.py operates in the test environment with dummy data. So you have to make sure that the data is exist and you are asserting it with the code. Although you can put a condition to check whether user exists or not.

Comment: This is what I'm saying. I create user 'testuser', I assert if 'testuser' exists, it passes. So I go back to alter my test, instead of user 'testuser' I create user 'dummyuser', I assert if 'testuser' exists, it passes. But it shouldn't pass, because the user doesn't exist.